# Inserting data from a website into another website using AJAX or an iframe

Tags: javascript, ajax, iframe, get

I have been given an address with a basic HTML structure, it just has some numbers in it. I have tried doing it as an Iframe, if I create a simple HTML that does work fine, but in the page itself if i hover over the iframe it says that it refused the connection.

I have tried with AJAX, but it does give me a mixed content error, since my page where I want the content inserted is secure (https) and the page where the numbers are is not.

Is there any workaround I can do in this case?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is because of CORS(cross domain access) problem:

if you are accessing the URL on same domain there won't be any problem but if you accessing content of another domain there is security issue.

this is possible only by below concepts:

1. Enabling CORs - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS
2. Image pinging concepts - limited to data size
3. JSONP